# OS file from BLOB in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm thinking about is it whether possible to write Oracle blobs to OS files. On first glance it is possible only using external procedures but may be something changed....

> How to save a BLOB to a file on disk in PL/SQL From: Thomas Kyte
>
> Use DBMS_LOB to read from the BLOB
>
> You will need to create an external procedure to take binary data and
>   write it to the operating system, the external procedure can be
>   written in C. If it was CLOB data, you can use UTL_FILE to write it to
>   the OS but UTL_FILE does not support the binary in a BLOB.

Comment: From 10g onward UTL_FILE does support `raw` data. Take a look at [UTL_FILE.put_raw](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i997577). So you are easily can put your `BLOB` to an OS file.

Comment: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/export-blob-9i.php - the example

Comment: Oh. I've neglected the fact that 9i has it(`put_raw` function) too. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations of files from table to OS files de SO, using DB Job

Example base on table fou_archvos, it has files on column "archivo", id+nombre will be concatenated.

```
SQL> desc fou_archvos
Name      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID        NOT NULL NUMBER
NOMBRE      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(300)
ACTIVO      NOT NULL CHAR(1)
ARCHIVO        BLOB
```

Create a folder on OS, it should have permission OS Oracle user owner.

```
su - oracle
mkdir /tmp/fou_archvo
```

Create a directory object on DB, eg TUKLI_FOU_ARCHVOS, grant permission to a scheme where be the procedure, eg PROD.

```
connect system/***@DB
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TUKLI_FOU_ARCHVOS AS '/tmp/fou_archvos';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY TUKLI_FOU_ARCHVOS TO PROD;
```

Crear el TU24X7_ARCHVES_TO_OSFILE.prc en PROD scheme, object

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TU24X7_ARCHVES_TO_OSFILE(p_from_id number default null )
as
    l_file    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    l_buffer    RAW(32767);
    l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
    l_pos     INTEGER;
    --l_blob    BLOB;
    l_blob_len  INTEGER;
    l_id    varchar2(10);
BEGIN
    FOR rFile IN (SELECT archivo, to_char(id)||'_'||nombre filename 
                    FROM fou_archvos 
                    where 1=1 
                    and id >= nvl(p_from_id,id)
                ) 
        LOOP
            l_pos := 1;
            l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(rFile.archivo);
            l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('TUKLI_FOU_ARCHVOS',rFile.filename,'wb', 32767);
            WHILE l_pos <= l_blob_len LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.read(rFile.archivo, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
            UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
            l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
        END LOOP;

        -- Close the file.
        UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Close the file if something goes wrong.
        IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
        UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
        END IF;
        RAISE;

END;
/
```

Execure using JOB DB
    connect PROD/XX@DB

```
declare
    l_jobid number := null;
    begin
    dbms_job.submit 
                (
                    job     =>  l_jobid,
                    what    =>  'TU24X7_ARCHVES_TO_OSFILE;',
                    next_date =>  sysdate,
                    interval  =>  null
                );
    commit;
end;
/
```